# Kerdi Board installation gaps

Tags: shower, installation, kerdi

this is my first time installing kerdi boards, and just have a couple questions.

As I was installing my kerdi board to my studs, I noticed that there were some gaps between the wall / board and my flange/board. If I attempt to straighten the contact between the board and tub, the gap between the board and wall become larger, and vice versa. My question is if the gaps are a huge issue, or if I can just fill them with the kerdi fix/mortar and band respectively. Or if I align my board with the tub flange, and the wall gap is larger, is that ok to be filled with mortar and band?

The last Q I have is I noticed that my bottom board projects out about 1/4" from the top board. I don't have a stud behind it, but I could add a blocking in that one spot behind it. I feel like I already know the answer, but is it important that I pull that in?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Projection of bottom board]

[image: Gap between wall and board]

[image: Gap between base and board]

Comment: One word of advice on your niche that you have - make sure when you place the tile there that you very slightly angle the bottom towards the shower area so it drains.  Otherwise, it'll collect water there and won't drain nicely.  This can probably be done with just some extra mortar in the back, since you already have your Kerdi board there flat.

Comment: The board below the joint can't be pulled tighter?